# Swift. How to allow dragging an URL from the browser to a NSView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nspasteboard

I have an NSView that accepts dropped files and store their fileURLs but I'd like it to accept HTTP URLs dragged from an Internet Browser as well. I mean, the same behavior as dragging it to Finder to create a .webloc file but inside my app.
What's the proper PasteboardType to use? I've tried .fileContents, .urL, .fileURL, .html, .string… to no avail.

EDIT: This is the relevant code as requested:

```
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: coder)

    wantsLayer = true
    layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor

    registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType"), .URL, .string, .html])
}

override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {

    showFrame(true)

    return .copy
}

override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {

    showFrame(false)
}

override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) {

    showFrame(false)
}

override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

    if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType")) as? NSArray
    {
        print("FILE: \(board)")
        return true
    } else if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: .URL) as? NSArray {
        print("URL: \(board)")
        return true
    } else if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: .string) as? NSArray {
        print("STRING: \(board)")
        return true
    } else if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard.propertyList(forType: .html) as? NSArray {
        print("HTML: \(board)")
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

EDIT AGAIN:

I've found what is the problem. It turns out that I have a tableview inside this NSView and it is registered for .string dragged types too (to be able to reorder the cells). It seems the table "swallows" the URL type but let the filenames pass through. I'll have to handle this issue but this is another question.

Comment: Type `.URL`, `.string` and `.html` should work, post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the pasteboard is not a property list and `URL` is not a property list compatible class. Use `readObjects(forClasses:options:)` instead of `propertyList(forType:)`.

```
if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().readObjects(forClasses: [NSURL.self]) {
    print("URL: \(board)")
    return true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't working. I mean, I wasn't able to test it since the delegate methods are not called when I drag an URL from Safari's address bar. It seems the problem is in registering the types.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: In fact, the edited post contains all I'm using (showFrame just adds/remove a border to the view). Delegate methods are called if I drag a file from desktop but not when I drag the URL from a browser

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project? I created a new Xcode project, added a `View` class, added your code, added my snippet, removed `showFrame`, set the class of the view in the storyboard to `View` and it works.

Comment: Well, I really don't know what happens but, in fact, your answer is right. I have created a new project, I've added the SAME class file to it and… it worked! I don't have a clue what's preventing it to get the browser urls in my app though. I'll keep searching. Thank you very much for your help, Willeke.